# heroku cronjob schedular addon error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
manish@ubuntu:~/project/myapp$  heroku addons:open scheduler
Opening scheduler:standard for myapp... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
Ruby version is too old

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/gagan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/byebug-4.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/gagan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/byebug-4.0.5/gem_make.out
(Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/addressable-2.3.2/lib/addressable/idna/native.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/addressable-2.3.2/lib/addressable/idna.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/addressable-2.3.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/launchy-2.4.2/lib/launchy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:327:in `block in launchy'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:227:in `action'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:326:in `launchy'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:179:in `open'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:37:in `start'
/usr/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku addons:open scheduler
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.9.0 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

when i try heroku run ruby -v i get

> ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

when i try ruby -v on local i get this version of ruby

> ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i686-linux]

when i push code to heroku i get the below one

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.2
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using minitest 5.5.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Using rack 1.6.0
remote:        Using mime-types 2.4.3
remote:        Using arel 6.0.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using chronic 0.10.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Using execjs 2.4.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.0
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using daemons 1.2.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using eventmachine 1.0.7
remote:        Using libv8 3.16.14.7
remote:        Using mysql2 0.3.18
remote:        Using pg 0.18.1
remote:        Using rack-offline 0.6.4 from git://github.com/wycats/rack-offline.git (at master)
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Using ref 1.0.5
remote:        Using rubyzip 1.1.7
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.0.7
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.3
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Using figaro 1.1.0
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.3
remote:        Using thin 1.6.3
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using therubyracer 0.12.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.1
remote:        Using roo 2.0.1
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.3
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.0
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.2.12
remote:        Using whenever 0.9.2
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.0
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.7
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.0
remote:        Using carrierwave 0.10.0
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.0
remote:        Using friendly_id 5.0.5
remote:        Using paperclip 4.2.1
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.0
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.0
remote:        Using railties 4.2.0
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Using rails 4.2.0
remote:        Using responders 2.1.0
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.3
remote:        Using rest_in_place 2.5.0
remote:        Using colorbox-rails 0.1.2
remote:        Using devise 3.4.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 76 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (0.65s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (6.42s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 51.6MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v234
remote:        https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
```

Comment: See if Ruby version is defined in your Gemfile. Like `ruby '1.9.1'`

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby version you are using (1.9.1) is not supported by heroku anymore.
The [Github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/.travis.yml) profile states you need to use at least 1.9.3.
Are you using rvm? if not you should still be able to install ruby 1.9.3, but make sure you do not use any gems that are outdated and might break after upgrading ruby.

I have no experience using heroku. But following [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) you must declare the ruby version you are using inside your Gemfile, is that the case?

```
Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.1.5"
```

To work, it will probably require to recommit and push your app to heroku.

You should also check further down the page to see how you can specify the desired ruby version inside you environment.rb

Comment: but am using 2.1.5 ruby version from rvm

Comment: Unfortunately your app isn't: `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb`. Do you have a .rvmrc file inside your project folder? what does `ruby -v` return after `cd to/your/project`?

Comment: manish@ubuntu:~/manish/myapp$ ruby -v
`ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i686-linux]`

Comment: I would say that this looks ok, but your app (or the webserver, probably nginx) is not picking up on that. I have updated my answer, maybe this will help.

Comment: rvmrc not in project folder and Gemfile configuraion was as above mentioned

Comment: Why wouldn't you place the `.rvmrc` in your project folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84206/discussion-between-manish-kongari-and-the-f).